# Why is it bad to change prototypes (js)?

Tags: javascript, dom, prototype

Why is it bad to write such a code?

```
Element.prototype.hide = function () { this.hidden = true };

Element.prototype.show = function () { this.hidden = false };
```

Comment: Some reading: http://perfectionkills.com/extending-native-builtins/

Comment: And previously on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean to change native JS prototypes(like `String`) or in general?

Changing native prototypes can be problematic since you can never know if there is another library, which does the same but gives e.g. slightly different results.

Changing prototypes of your objects / third-party libraries is perfectly fine because this is how polymorphism in JS can be achieved.

Comment: I mean to change native js prototypes. Is it only one reason that other libraries can change them too?

Comment: Of course not but this is the main reason - to avoid confusion.